# How do you make a row in a table view go slighly see through if a checkbox in that row is checked?

Tags: cocoa, checkbox

I am looking to make a Application and each row of the table view will have a column with a check box. What i am looking to do is... make the row that the checkbox is on go slightly see through if the check box on that row is checked (this should be implemented on every row of the table as every row has a checkbox) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table view delegate, implement this method:

```
tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

From there you can get the checkbox button cell at the given row, and change the cell's drawing style based on it's state. Keep in mind though that cells are re-used, so you'll have to set the cell style for both checked and unchecked states.

I'm not too clear on what sort of drawing style you're aiming for. Try with a basic NSTextFieldCell first and if you can't accomplish what you're trying to do, create an NSCell subclass and handle the drawing code yourself.

Comment: I'm using core data so where would i add that?

Comment: Your table view's delegate methods are called regardless of whether you're feeding it data with bindings or a data source object. If you don't know how delegation works in Cocoa yet it might be a good idea to hold off on using bindings and stick with data source methods. It's really important to understand the basics well, or you're going to run into problems with things like bindings.

Answer (score -2):

Do you really mean "opaque"?  ("Slightly opaque" is a lot like "slightly pregnant.")

If you mean change the color, add javascript to the checkbox to change the background of the div containing the checkbox.  Here's an [example](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-144799.html).

Comment: From his tags it looks like he's working on a Cocoa program, not a webapp.

Comment: By opaque i meant to say slightly see-through.

Comment: Opaque means the opposite. Completely solid, zero transparency.